# Access dynamic form id of rails in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form with a dynamic `edit_user_dynamic_id`. How do I access it in jQuery. Below is the code in `app.js` but it seems not working.

```
$(function() {
  $('#edit_user_<%= @user.id %>').submit(function(){

  })
})
```

Comment: @adeneo: sorry that was a typo from my side.

Comment: What if you put this code in the view file and not in a javascript file?

Comment: adding `<div style="border:2px solid red"><%= @user.id %></div>`on to the page somewhere, what do you see ?

Comment: app.js is static, or server side rendered ?

Comment: @RobSedgwick: What does that mean?. How to verify it?.

Comment: @zwippie: I am getting the dynamic id displayed a 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your external JavaScript file is treated as a static file and isn't processed by the server side script.

Option 1: in the view, output the user ID with a script tag:

```
<script>var userId = "<%= @user.id %>";</script>
```

Now, all external JavaScript files will be able to get the `userId`:

```
$('#edit_user_' + userId).submit(function(){

})
```

---

Option 2: use a [starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector to match any element with an ID that starts with `edit_user_`:

```
$('form[id^="edit_user_"]').submit(function(){

});
```

Comment: The second one works, can you explain me on the why is my JS file treated as static and how to make it server-side.

Comment: JavaScript, CSS, images etc etc are not typically processed by server side languages because they don't usually need server side variables. If they do, the most common solution is to output the variable as in the answer. If that isn't working, check the HTML source to see if the variable is outputted as it should be. Also have it before any other JavaScript.

Comment: Is this the rails way, I feel it strange. Any way we can execute the ruby on a pure JS file.